# Why the image gets pixelated when using the transform property

Tags: html, css

I want to make a rotating animation for the search icon, that when the input gets focused, then the icon rotates 90 degrees around the Y-axis, and then the text cursor appears, so it's like the search icon being transformed into the text cursor (try it with the code snippet below), but when I apply the transform property to the icon which is a png image, it gets pixelated and it doesn't look good, Is there a way to fix this problem?

Here's the difference:

[image]

```css
.Navbar {
    display: flex;
    padding: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.Navbar .SearchBox {
    position: relative;
}
.Navbar .SearchBox input {
    background-color: darkgray;
    border-style: none;
    color: transparent;
    padding: 0px 16.5px 0px 10px;
    font-family: 'vazir';
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 35px;
    outline: none;
    width: 300px;
    direction: rtl;
}
.Navbar .SearchBox img {
    height: 17px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    right: 8px;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}
.Navbar .SearchBox input:focus {
    color: white;
    transition: color 0s ease .3s;
}
.Navbar .SearchBox input:focus + img {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="Navbar">
        <div class="SearchBox">
            <input type="text">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/DRLFR0w/search.png" alt="search">
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you define a transformation on the element it will create a new stacking context which will make the element have its own path in the renderer. Chrome apparently applies a different antialiasing algorithm for such elements in their own stacking context.

To workaround that, you can simply omit that rule and let the transition start from `initial`:

```css
body{ background: #333 }
img { height: 17px; }
.transform {
  transition: transform .3s ease-out;
}
:hover>.transform {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span><img src="https://i.ibb.co/DRLFR0w/search.png" alt="search"></span>
<span>
<img class="transform" src="https://i.ibb.co/DRLFR0w/search.png" alt="search"></span>
```